# How to dynamically set Module URL property in Elements.xml file

Tags: visual-studio, feature, publishing

I have created a module that creates a site page inside a pages library.  Is there a way we can dynamically set Url property of the Module node in the XML file?  I would like to set the Url property dynamically, so that it will allow easier deployment between environments (i.e. Dev, QA, Prod).  Thinking about using a Farm Level Property, Web Config key, etc.

```
 <Module Name="pages" Url="pages" List="101">
```

Comment: This url is relative so should not matter which environment you are deploying unless you want to deploy in different libraries in different environments.. is that the case?

Comment: yes.  I need to deploy to different libraries.  Is there a way to do this?  Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: IMO cannot be done without custom coding.  You need to write an feature receiver code which will read url from web.config/web/farm property and upload the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Scoped Features with Relative Paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Name="TestDocLibrary" Url="TestDocLibrary" RootWebOnly="FALSE">
        <File Path="TestDocLibrary\doc1.doc" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Url="doc1.doc" Name="doc1.doc" />
        <File Path="TestDocLibrary\doc2.doc" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Url="doc2.doc" Name="doc2.doc" />
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

This puts two files in the TestDocLibrary of the web that the feature was activated on.